# RequestError when calling the CreateHIT operation

Tags: python, mechanicalturk

I'm new to MTurk, and Im trying to create a HIT using python.
I successfully connected to sandbox (by printing successfully my account balance).
I'm now trying to create a HIT and get a request error. I would like to know what have I missed.

```
import boto3

region_name = 'us-east-1'
aws_access_key_id = 'MYID'
aws_secret_access_key = 'MYSECRETKEY'

endpoint_url = 'https://mturk-requester-sandbox.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'

# Uncomment this line to use in production
# endpoint_url = 'https://mturk-requester.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
create_hits_in_live = False

environments = {
        "live": {
            "endpoint": "https://mturk-requester.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
            "preview": "https://www.mturk.com/mturk/preview",
            "manage": "https://requester.mturk.com/mturk/manageHITs",
            "reward": "0.00"
        },
        "sandbox": {
            "endpoint": "https://mturk-requester-sandbox.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
            "preview": "https://workersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/preview",
            "manage": "https://requestersandbox.mturk.com/mturk/manageHITs",
            "reward": "0.11"
        },
}
mturk_environment = environments["live"] if create_hits_in_live else environments["sandbox"]
session = boto3.Session()


client = boto3.client(
    'mturk',
    endpoint_url=endpoint_url,
    region_name=region_name,
    aws_access_key_id=aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key=aws_secret_access_key,
)

# This will return $10,000.00 in the MTurk Developer Sandbox
print(client.get_account_balance()['AvailableBalance'])

question_sample = open("q.xml", "r").read()

worker_requirements = [{ 
    'QualificationTypeId': '000000000000000000L0',
    'Comparator': 'GreaterThanOrEqualTo',
    'IntegerValues': [80],
    'RequiredToPreview': True,
}]

response = client.create_hit(
    MaxAssignments=3,
    LifetimeInSeconds=604800,
    AssignmentDurationInSeconds=600,
    Reward=mturk_environment['reward'],
    Title='title',
    Keywords='question, answer, research',
    Description='description.',
    Question=question_sample,
    QualificationRequirements=worker_requirements
)
```

The error the been raised:

```
botocore.errorfactory.RequestError: An error occurred (RequestError) when 
calling the CreateHIT operation: Please log in to the appropriate MTurk UI 
and complete registration. (1539419496875 s)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen when your Mechanical Turk isn't correctly linked to your AWS account. Have you completed the linking steps from the [Getting Started Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSMechTurk/latest/AWSMechanicalTurkGettingStartedGuide/SetUp.html#accountlinking)? Note that you need to link the sandbox and production separately, buy logging into each of those sites and going through the linking steps. There's also a [blog post discussing these steps](https://blog.mturk.com/tutorial-setting-up-your-aws-account-to-make-use-of-mturks-api-4e405b8fc8cb).

Comment: I did all those steps

Comment: If it works in sandbox but not prod, and your account is linked in both sites, everything should be working. You may need to contact AWS customer support.